# Python API and Salesforce Rest API Data discrepancy in returning number of records

Tags: python, rest, salesforce, crm, sfdc

I have developed version 3 python API from version 2 the code and everything remains same for except for few querying data but the WHERE clause remains same for both versions when i try to query from the data directly on sfdc it gives me same number or records which means there is no issue with the query but response which i am getting for v3 is 125 records and for v3 its 250 records is this something related to sfdc or python API?

```
response = client.post("/composite", data=body, **kwargs)
records = []
for r in response.get("compositeResponse", ()):
    if r["httpStatusCode"] >= 300:
        continue
    if flatten:
        for rec in r["body"]["records"]:
            records.append(rec)
    else:
        records.append(r["body"]["records"])
return records
```

the client here is sfdclib.rest.SfdcRestApi object at 0x7ffb887a99d0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

composite is special. Do you get same number of results when you run each "inner" query manually? Maybe some of them just have the `nextrecordsurl` set but you ignore it and retrieve only 1st "page" of results.

Comment: No when I run the query manually it returns all the records.its  only when  I make a post request to /composite endpoint and get the response.

Comment: Why composite? What happens when you make a normal rest API query? Do you need to collect data from different tables in one go?

Comment: Yes I need to collect data from different table looks like you are correct it is indeed sending back the `nextrecords` URL.

Comment: Is there anyway that i can handle that `nextrecordsurl` data with one request to composite API?

Comment: Never tried but you should be able to issue next composite request where each sub request would be nextrecordsurl you just received... Or even invent your own ones, once you got 1st you can guess the suffix with "start from record 2000, 4000" etc